# How to get % of Sub Total in QuickSight Pivot Table?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I need to get the % of the subtotal in the quick sight Pivot table.
I tried percentofTotal function but it is not working. I would appreciate any kind of help.

I tried percenoftotal function. But Its not what I am looking for. I need % of SubTotal. The screen shot of the table is attached below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWfMC.png)